# Why doesn't by program reverse the values of the array correctly?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int myArray [5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    for(int count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        myArray[count] = myArray[4-count];
    }

    for(int Count = 0; Count < 5; Count++)
    {
        cout<<myArray[Count]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Output is 50,40,30,40,50 instead of 50,40,30,20,10. Any idea what's wrong with the logic of this program? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try to write down on a paper what your program does, step by step (in the loop).

Comment: Okay. I'll do that.. thanks for the tip

Comment: You are not swapping the elements .For first half it's ok but the last half you copy the previously copy ie. new values. Either use 2nd new `array` or apply swapping till half of array elements

Comment: You want to swap values. And for this, you 'll need a temp, for example: `int temp = value1; value1 = value2; value2 = temp;`

Comment: Think about just the first iteration. You are over writing the 10 with 50, the 10 is now gone. It would be better to iterate n/2 times and do swaps rather than overwrite the values

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! This was of immense help!

Comment: Implicit `int` has never been valid in C++. Fixed that `main` declaration for you.

Comment: BTW, if you include `<algorithm>` you can use `std::reverse(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray));` to accomplish the same task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go over the code one iteration at a time:

```
 myArray [5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

1st iteration:

```
 myArray [5] = {50, 20, 30, 40, 50};
```

2nd iteration:

```
 myArray [5] = {50, 40, 30, 40, 50};
```

3rd iteration:

```
 myArray [5] = {50, 40, 30, 40, 50};
```

4th iteration:

```
 myArray [5] = {50, 40, 30, 40, 50};
```

5th iteration:

```
 myArray [5] = {50, 40, 30, 40, 50};
```

to make it work as expected change the loop to swap the values insist of overwriting them. like:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    tmp = arr[4-i];
    myArray[4-i] = myArray[i];
    myArray[i] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are changing the array `in-place`, thus changing the initially provided array continuously, and consequently accessing the changed values.

To be able to reverse the array, you mustn't lose the value provided initially till the end of the complete reversing procedure.